# Getting this error while integrating paypal in my android application , end SEND_PAYMENT fail, ANDROID_569059

Tags: android, paypal, chained-payments, adaptive-parallel-payment

```
Response contains an error, <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns2:ExecutePaymentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap"><responseEnvelope>    <timestamp>2016-07-20T03:26:52.691-07:00</timestamp><ack>Success</ack><correlationId>654a4ab712f4c</correlationId><build>23046607</build></responseEnvelope><paymentExecStatus>ERROR</paymentExecStatus><payErrorList><payError><receiver><amount>20.00</amount><email>primaryuser@email.com</email><primary>true</primary><paymentType>SERVICE</paymentType></receiver><error><errorId>569059</errorId><domain>PLATFORM</domain><severity>Error</severity><category>Application</category><message>Instant payments can't be pending</message></error></payError></payErrorList></ns2:ExecutePaymentResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am getting the above response when trying to make adaptive payment in sandbox

Comment: your question is not clear. [You have to provide the additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your code, the request and the reply you are getting.

Comment: using sandbox??

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan yes using sandbox but I have figured it out thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your email is not cabaple to receive the payment so the error occuring!